# Print values using a for loop but filter certain values without findstr command

Tags: batch-file

The batch script I'm using has this code in it:

```
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN

for /L %%a in (0 1 10) do (
for /L %%b in (1 1 10) do (
set X=%%a%%b
echo. !X!
)) >>newfile.txt

rem ----> findstr /V "11 22 33 44 55 66" ABCD.txt > outfile.txt
```

Here's what the above outputs to the file

> ```
> 11
> 12
> 13
> .
> .
> .
> 98
> 99
> ```

My problem is that I do not want to see same duplicate numbers or values like (11,22,33....), in text file when both the first loop and second loop variables are the same.

I can put `findstr` command in the mix (comment out in the script) to filter it in 2nd new text file but I'd like to see if this is possible by just using  using for loops?

I mean that `echo. !X!` is displaying results I want to add `!X!` in another for loop which checks `!X!` , if it contains `11` or `22` or `55` ... I need it to just skip those values (the same) and proceed further `echo.` remaining values in text file that are not the same from both loops.

Comment: is there any way to add another for loop for deleting or skipping UNWANTED values which can be defined.... and remaining values will be filter and save in text file as per coding.

Comment: you can use "modulo" to determine if the value is divisible by 10 and only echo when it is. I think that the mod operator is `%%` in batch files. It will return the remainder, so `11 mod 11 = 0`, `22 mod 11 = 0` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use some simple conditional [`IF NOT`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and tell it if the first `FOR /L` variable of `%%a` is equal to the value of the second `FOR /L` variable of `%%b` to not [`echo`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) to the output file.

I also put the `>>` append redirect to the `echo` of the `%X%` variable within the loop to ensure it appends to correct values from the loops as you expected. Additionally I put the initial logic up top of `IF EXIST newfile.txt DEL /Q /F newfile.txt` so if it exist before the run, it is deleted first.

```
@ECHO ON
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

IF EXIST newfile.txt DEL /Q /F newfile.txt
for /L %%a in (0 1 10) do ( 
    for /L %%b in (1 1 10) do ( 
        IF NOT %%a==%%b set X=%%a%%b
        echo. !X! >>newfile.txt
))
```

### Example Output

---

### Further Resources

- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [ECHO](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)

Comment: Hye! you explanation is nice, is there any way to add a for loop. where i have defined "unwanted" values such as ..(set unwanted=11 22 33..) because probelm is that if i add two more for loops in same just like ::::::CODE START ::::::   for /L %%a in (0 1 10) do ( 
    for /L %%b in (1 1 10) do (  for /L %%a in (0 1 10) do ( 
    for /L %%b in (1 1 10) do (  ::::::CODE END ::::::    it will generate 1111, 2222 , 3333 something like these... how can i do this  where for loops are in more than two loops ... any predefined ceriteria which i mentioned above (Set unwanted=1111 2222 ... 8888 9999)

Comment: @echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN

for /L %%a in (0 1 10) do (
for /L %%b in (1 1 10) do (
for /L %%c in (1 1 10) do (
for /L %%d in (1 1 10) do (

set X=%%a%%b%%c%%d

echo. !X!
)) >>newfile.txt
rem --> findstr /V "1111 2222 5544 6667 9987" newfile.txt > outfile.txt


I dont want to use findstr, instead of this i want to use any for loop which stop predefined values to print (just like findstr filter unwanted values) and remain will proceed as normal.

Comment: yes your understanding is correct... i want a set of numbers which I dont want in output... 6667 9987 5544 etc these are correct examples.... if it is possible so i can do any job either duplicate same or anything i can omit these values from output.... !!!!!! but remember findstr is very very slow I need a solution for this which is very fast just like for loop is running and giving output another for loop is running filtering values and saving it into text file.... thats really like a charmmmm......   you understanding is right.... waiting for you expert advise..... thanks

Comment: I have written new code for more better understanding if this resolve so lots of questions will be resolved.... plz follow this http://textuploader.com/dxvhx and take necessary action on it.

Comment: is there any one else to help me out in this scenario???

Comment: my all best wishes with u in all ur challenging projects,if you only see my 2nd last post, this is exactly what is want, u will find 1 thing is common in my first code and 2nd last code I want only omit few bunch of unwanted values which i dont want to print without findstr function, either you generate 1to10 or a=z does'nt matter, the goal is an array defined in code (set deleted= aa bb cc 11 22 ...) and those values are include in this array, these will not include in output. forget everything just try understand my this & 2nd last post every thing wil be clear and thank you 4 ur attention

Comment: Yes, this is quite a simple way to do this with findstr, anything else except findstr OR another solution for a same task and with same output?

Comment: can any one else help me out of this!!!!!

Comment: Dear the motive of this idea has not fulfil the basic concern for not using fndstr commmand was speed, whereas it is too much slow as compare to fndstr, i hope you can do this with great skill. see this again http://textuploader.com/dxvhx and do needful.

Comment: @AdnanZarrar Did you try my new method of http://textuploader.com/dunbo and set the `SET delete="11","22","33","44"` to have the values you wish to have omitted? Take a look at that one and report back whether or not this will do what you ask as per my testing and my understanding of your needs, this appears to do exactly what you ask a much much faster than `findstr`.

Comment: @AdnanZarrar Did you see my comment above with the link http://textuploader.com/dunbo and if so, did you run thru it because I did and it worked just as expected and way way faster than `findstr`.... I've cleaned up the older comments that are not needed so only this comment and the other with the NEW logic I have for you that I confirmed worked as per your description and performs much better than the `findstr` method.... With kindest regards, please update me on your status after you look it over, I have something else for you too so tag me back and check back in and don't disappear.

Comment: if we put unwanted values like11,22,33,44 in findstr and output in text file, it is working 3 to 4 times faster than your solution, the basic concern of not using findstr, is only the more faster solution infront of findstr, if you still any confuse so please check both of it hope it will be cleared.

Comment: @AdnanZarrar I apologize but I'm having a hard time following you with clarity. Have you looked at the logic I saved to this link here http://textuploader.com/dunbo which you can click on and see the code I am asking you to test with here http://textuploader.com/dunbo. Did you test with the code I saved for you on this link here http://textuploader.com/dunbo. Please confirm if you tried with this http://textuploader.com/dunbo and tell me your results with it? These all point to the same one link so check it out here: textuploader.com/dunbo and report back your results after running that code??